# Chrome DevTools Autosave 0.3.2 - Not working. Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, autosave

I don't get this.

Going to `http://127.0.0.1:9104/` informs me that DevTools Autosave 0.3.2 is running well.

The terminal console records: `30-05-2012 15:49:50: Saved a stylesheet to /Users/me/Desktop/boxes.css`

But the stylesheet is NOT updating with my changes.

I've looked at the extension plugin console for any errors. There are no errors.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome, restarted my computer, installed the latest version of Chrome, etc. with no change.

Comment: The location you're trying to edit, is it a `file:///` or `http://`?

Comment: @Grigore-Tubodisel `file:///`

Comment: Does this mean it's not compatible with the latest Google Chrome and I should somehow install a previous version? https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave/issues/40

Comment: Got it. Closed. It works in the Stable version of Chrome.